# Ordinal numbers in Microsoft Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with ranks. Now I want the ranks to have the suffixes 'St', 'nd', 'rd', 'th' in Microsoft Access. I want to know if there is a way to make that happen using access query. Thanks for the response in advance

Comment: I think your best bet in Access is going to be creating a VBA function that takes a number and returns its "ordinalized" variant. You can then call this function in your query: `SELECT nbr, ordinalize(nbr) FROM TableWithNumbers`.

Comment: I tried your function and I'm getting this error "undefined function 'ordinalize' in expression.

Comment: Use @Darren's answer to write the function: My comment was just how to use it in a query (which Darren also describes).

Answer (score 1):

This code from [Chip Pearsons](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ordinal.aspx) site will do the trick:

```
Public Function OrdinalSuffix(ByVal Num As Long) As String
        Dim N As Long
        Const cSfx = "stndrdthththththth" ' 2 char suffixes
        N = Num Mod 100
        If ((Abs(N) >= 10) And (Abs(N) <= 19)) _
                Or ((Abs(N) Mod 10) = 0) Then
            OrdinalSuffix = "th"
        Else
            OrdinalSuffix = Mid(cSfx, _
                ((Abs(N) Mod 10) * 2) - 1, 2)
        End If
End Function
```

You'd write it into your query as:

```
SELECT MyField & OrdinalSuffix(MyField)
FROM   MyTable
```

The formula only version is:

```
 IIf(MyField-100*INT(MyField/100)>=10 And MyField-100*INT(MyField/100)<=14,"th",Choose(MyField-10*INT(MyField/10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th"))
```

Written as

```
SELECT MyField & IIf(MyField-100*INT(MyField/100)>=10 And MyField-100*INT(MyField/100)<=14,"th",Choose(MyField-10*INT(MyField/10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th"))
FROM   MyTable
```

Comment: **Darren** is there a way to to return a ranking value in its 'ordinalize form'? I was used this function in the query to get the ranking and yours to get the ordinal numbers. How can i get the ranking in its ordinal form direct.

Comment: This is the ranking function in the query.                                                                                                            SELECT StudentID, Surname, [Other Names], Class, [Mathematics 100%], 1+ (SELECT COUNT (T1.[Mathematics 100%]) 
                    FROM
                              [JHS Database Query] AS T1
                    WHERE T1.[Mathematics 100%]>T2.[Mathematics 100%]) AS Ranking
FROM [JHS Database Query] AS T2
ORDER BY [Surname];                   So how can I return ranking in its ordinalize form directly. Thank you

Comment: Without looking into your query too far I'd go with `SELECT  StudentID, Surname, [Other Names], Class, [Mathematics 100%], Ranking & IIf(Ranking-100*INT(Ranking/100)>=10 And Ranking-100*INT(Ranking/100)<=14,"th",Choose(Ranking-10*INT(Ranking/10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th"))
FROM    First_Query` in a new query.